# vue addRoutes refresh after not work

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

#### My project need use "Access control":

For example:

- User '1' can access to the page a and page b, can't access the page c and page d.
- User '2' can access to the page c and page d, can't access the page a and page b.

I can use the vue-router `addRoutes` method ,I think.

In the file "login.vue", show me the code:

```
// more code

// User login success
sessionStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));

// From server get the routes data
getRoutes().then(data => {

  // Routes data save in to sessionStorage
  sessionStorage.setItem('routes', JSON.stringify(data.routes));

  // Format data && created vue Router object
  let routes = this.routeCreater(data.routes);

  // addRoutes
  this.$router.addRoutes(routes);

  this.$router.push({ path: '/Index' });
})

// more code
```

Routes normal work.but, if i refresh this page(press the 'F5' key). use `addRoutes()` dynamic add routes not work.

Please help me. Thx.